# Creating a button dynamically and invoking an action from it

Tags: android, button, runtime, invoke

I'm doing programming in Android. I'm creating a button dynamically(i.e, at runtime without using layout). Now I need to invoke an action from that dynamically created button. Is that possible?

I've used the following code for dynamically creating the button.

```js
Button btnNew = new Button(this);
String text = etName.getText().toString();
btnNew.setText(text);
llMain.addView(btnNew, lParams);
```

Now I need to invoke/trigger something using `btnNew`

All helps are appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform several events on that particular button by setting listeners

```
btnNew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: what if I'm creating several buttons at runtime using the same code?

Comment: dynamically set id to button

Comment: Can you please explain how to assign id for each and every button I create using the same code?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
 Button btnNew = new Button(this);
 btnNew.setId(111);
 btnNew.setOnClickListener(this);

 Button btn2 = new Button(this);
 btn2.setId(222);
 btn2.setOnClickListener(this);

 you can implement onclick listener in your activity
```

In onclcik view you can check the ids like below

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case 111:
            //do some thing here
           break;
         case 222:
            //do some thing here
           break;
 }
};
```

Comment: @Ramesh- thanks. But this is for the case of a single button I create. When I create another button, it's id will also be set as `111` and is refered to the previous button. So how could i refer to the second button?

Comment: you can give different id for another button

Comment: I need 5 buttons for now.

Comment: Then mantain 5 different ids like 1,2,3,4,5 and assign to each button and check in switch case which button triggered like case 1,case 2,case 3 like that

Comment: I understood that. But `btnNew.setId(111);` this line of code for 5 buttons is a bit confusing. How could I implement? Where to place this line?

Comment: so how could I invoke `llMain.addView(btnNew, lParams);` to add buttons to my layout when I declare & define multiple buttons manually rather than creating them at runtime using same code?

Answer (score 0):

you can perform several action on button with "OnClickListener"

```
btnNew.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //action here .. which you want to perform
        }
    });
```

Comment: yes I know this method. But I need to assign listener for 5 different buttons created at runtime using the same line of codes.

Comment: @Lijin..  where are these 5 buttons ?

Comment: I've set a button to perform this button creation. i.e, a button named create to create buttons at runtime. So, whenever I touch create button, a button is created in the screen dynamically. My intention is to set id for each button so that I can perform different operations with the created buttons. The button id I set can later be used inside a switch to perform required operations.

Comment: ok it looks like you hide visibility on button and they will visible on button click ... so you should  set OnClickListener on each button ... when you shown these button on run time then they will work as you set action ...

Comment: It seems to be working. Could you please elaborate how can I implement it?

Comment: go for nameOfButton1.setOnClickListener ... then perform action .. then for button 2 3 4 5 ....

Comment: if you show your button on run time .. even in this condition you have to write code for them ... they will pick there coding when thay are visible ...

Comment: I cannot declare & define multiple buttons manually rather than creating them at runtime. Because I'm reusing the code to create multiple buttons dynamically. i.e, button has same object name. All I need is to use same code to create many buttons dynamically, but each button should have a different id, by which I can refer those buttons and perform required task.

Comment: ok ... you gave name to single button .... then you want different action with different button name ...

Comment: Yes. I declared and defined a button btnNew for dynamic button creation. Then I set name for each button at runtime. So, each button will be different and I can perform different actions. This is what I'm about to do.

Comment: i think there is a confusion ... plz provide your .java and .xml file

Answer (score 0):

**You may use the code below:**

```
Button dynamicBtn = new Button(this); // or new Button(getActivity());
dynamicBtn.setTag(100);
dynamicBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

// Override below in fragment or activity that implements 
// 'View.OnClickListener'

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        switch ((Integer)v.getTag()) {
        case 100:
            //do something
           break;
        default:
           break;
 }
};
```

Comment: Is setTag() is similar to setId() or what?

Comment: setTag() is a lil different but can be used in the same and is a way around the resourceId required for setId(). setTag also enables you to pass any object as well, so its more convenient.

Comment: Yeah. Thats convenient. But the value passed inside `setTag()` is `100` which is a constant. So this value is same for all buttons created at runtime. How is it possible to refer the buttons individually and set action for them?

Comment: Well what I would do is create a class with an id field that is set randomly and also an interface callback that gets called in the onClick method, that would remove the use of the switch statement

Comment: could you please help me to implement that logic?

Comment: See my new answer to your question on this page

Answer (score 0):

```
Button dynamicButton = new Button(this);
dynamicButton.setTag(new ButtonTag(100, new ButtonTag.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run anything here
    }
}));

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ButtonTag tag = (ButtonTag)view.getTag();
    tag.execute();

    // simpler ((ButtonTag)view.getTag()).execute();
}

// don't think you need id anymore 
public static class ButtonTag{

    private Callback callback;
    private int id;

    public ButtonTag(int id, Callback callback){
        this.callback = callback;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void execute(){
        callback.run();
    }

    public interface Callback{
        public void run();
    }
}
```